# Degree of the twisted cubic curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I want to compute the degree of the twisted cubic curve $$X = \{xw = yz, xz=y^2, yw = z^2\} \subset \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^3 \ni [x:y:z:w].$$ I already know that $\deg(X) = 3$, however, I want to verify this claim by computing the degree of the intersection divisor $\operatorname{div}(x)$.

To this end, let $L: x= 0$. Then,

$$
X \cap L = \{yz = 0, y^2=0, yw = z^2\}
$$
contains only the point $p = [0:0:0:1]$, since $y^2 = 0$ implies $y = 0$ and hence, $z = 0$. If it is true that there is a unique intersection point, then, by definition, the degree of $X$ is the order of the meromorphic function $\tfrac{x}{w}$ at $p \in X$. Why is this equal to 3? The order is $2$ around $y^2 = 0$ and likewise, around $z^2 = 0$. I am not sure how one comes up with 3.

Comment: What definition of the degree are you using?

Comment: The degree of a smooth projective curve is the degree of (any) hyperplane divisor.

Comment: That is fine, but what does the function $x/w$ have to do with this.

Comment: If $\operatorname{div}(G)$ is any intersection divisor on a smooth projective curve $X$, then, at any point $p \in X$, where $G=0$, we define $\operatorname{div}(G)(p)$ to be the order of $G/H$ at $p$ where $H$ is a homogenous polynomial of the same degree as $G$ which does not vanish at $p$. If $G \neq 0$ at $p \in X$, then we set $\operatorname{div}(G)(p) = 0$. In our case, $G = x$ and  $H = w$ does not vanish at $p$, which explains why I consider $x/w$.

Comment: I don't understand this. What you need to compute in your example is the **length** of the finite scheme $X \cap L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition
$$
\deg(X) = \ell(X \cap L),
$$
the length of the finite scheme $X \cap L$.

To identify this scheme in $L \cong \mathbb{P}^2_{(y:z:w)}$ note that it lies in the affine chart $w \ne 0$, so we may take $w = 1$ and use $y$ and $z$ as coordinates. Then the equations become
$$
yz = 0,
\quad
y^2 = 0,
\quad
y = z^2.
$$
Using $y = z^2$ to eleminate $y$ we obtain $z^3 = z^4 = 0$ from the other two equations, hence
$$
X \cap L \cong \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[z]/z^3),
$$
hence its length is 3.

Comment: I am not familiar with schemes, but it seems like I can simply adopt the strategy to my ansatz. That is, just dehomogenize $X \cap L$ in the $w$-variable, then I get $z^3 = z^4 = 0$, as you did. The question which remains is, why are we throwing away the equation $z^4 = 0$ and keep $z^3=0$, and not the other way around?

Comment: Because $z^3 = 0$ implies $z^4 = 0$ and not the other way round.

Comment: Sure. On the other hand, $z^4 = 0$ implies $z = 0$ and this implies $z^3 = 0$. That is why I asked.

Comment: No, because the right language here is that of schemes, so what I mean is that the ideal in $\mathbb{C}[z]$ generated by $z^3$ contains $z^4$, but not the other way round.